# Scrape a paginated table in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Apologizes in advanced if this is very basic, but I'm lost on this!

I want to scrape the following table in R,

http://dgsp.cns.gob.mx/Transparencia/wConsultasGeneral.aspx

However, this page is written in, I believe, Java. I tried with RSelenium, but I am no having success in scraping the 17 pages of this table.

Could you give me a hint about how to scrape the entire content of this table?

Comment: It probably isn't written in Java. What have you tried? What hasn't worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given it's just 17 pages, I would manually click through the pages and save the HTML source. It would take no more than 3-5 minutes this way.

However, if you want to do it programmatically, we can start by writing a function that takes a page number, finds the link for that page, clicks on the link, and returns the HTML source for that page:

```
get_html <- function(i) {
  webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "link text", as.character(i))
  webElem$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(s)
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
}
```

Initialize some values:

```
s <- 2 # seconds to wait between each page
total_pages <- 17
html_pages <- vector("list", total_pages)
```

Start the browser, navigate to page 1, and save the source:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
base_url <- "http://dgsp.cns.gob.mx/Transparencia/wConsultasGeneral.aspx"
remDr$navigate(base_url)
src <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
html_pages[1] <- src
```

For pages 2 to 17, we use a for-loop and call the function we wrote above, taking care to account specially for page 11:

```
for (i in 2:total_pages) {
  if (i == 11) {
    webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = "link text", "...")
    webElem$clickElement()
    Sys.sleep(s)
    html_pages[i] <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  } else {
    html_pages[i] <- get_html(i)  
  }
}
remDr$close()
```

The result is `html_pages`, a list of length 17, with each element the HTML source for each page. How to parse the data from HTML into some other form (e.g. a dataframe) is probably a separate question by itself.

Comment: Thank you, this is excellent and structured advice on how to do this kind of thing. It has been very helpful to me in getting tables from [https://www.tauhead.com/item/list?item_type=weapon](https://www.tauhead.com/item/list?item_type=weapon)